# List empty elements found in an XML document using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, unique, is-empty

I want to produce a deduplicated list of all XML elements that are provided empty (contain the empty string) in an XML source document using XSLT:

INPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <empty1></empty1>
    <content1>Example</content1>
    <container1>
        <content2>Example</content2>
        <empty2></empty2>
    </container1>
    <empty2/>
</root>
```

OUTPUT:

```
empty1
empty2
```

Note:

- `empty2` is only listed once even though it appears >1.
- the second instance of `empty2` self-closes but it's still "empty".

Comment: We expect you to make a good-faith effort at solving the problem for yourself before bringing it to us, and to show that you have done so.  In case you are uncertain how even to approach the problem, I suggest that this looks like a job for [Muenchian grouping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT/Muenchian_grouping).

Comment: If you are using XSLT 2.0 or later you can also simply use the `distinct-values` function on the names of all empty elements `//*[not(node())]/name()`.